# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for A Particular Sum Rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Let $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a rearrangement of $\mathbb{N}$ (a bijection). I am searching for a condition equivalent to:
$$$$
For all complex sequences $(\alpha_n)$, there exists some $l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N},$
$$\sum_{n=0}^N(\alpha_{\phi_n}-\alpha_n)=O\left(\max_{|n-N|\leq l}|\alpha_n|\right).$$
So far, I've proven that if $(\phi_n-n)=O(1),$ then this condition follows. I then proved that if this condition holds, $\sum_{n=0}^N(\phi_n-n)=O(N)$ follows. Then, heuristically, I imagine there should be some condition, implied by $(\phi_n-n)=O(1),$ and implying $\sum_{n=0}^N(\phi_n-n)=O(N),$ which is equivalent to the condition above (and about as simply stated as each of these two conditions). Does anyone know of such a result? I know there are similar results about convergence-preserving rearrangements, though this condition is stronger in the following sense:
$$$$
Such a $\phi$ would have the following properties:
$$$$
(i) If $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right)$ converges, then $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_{\phi_n}\right)$ converges and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_{\phi_n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_n.$
$$$$
(ii) If $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right)$ is bounded, then $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_{\phi_n}\right)$ is bounded.
$$$$
(iii) If $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right)$ is unbounded, then $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_{\phi_n}\right)$ is unbounded.

Comment: I'm a tiny bit confused on your notation. By $\sum_{n=0}^N (\alpha_{\phi_n}-\alpha_n)=O(\max_{|n-N|\le \ell}|\alpha_n|)$, are you saying there exists some $C\in(0,\infty)$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\left|\sum_{n=0}^N(\alpha_{\phi_n}-\alpha_n)\right|\le C\max_{|n-N|\le \ell}|\alpha_n|$ or something else?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yes this is exactly what I'm saying. Where is your confusion?

Comment: Mainly because of the "for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$", but I just wanted to clarify to make sure.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I guess, more strictly, I mean there exists some $M$ such that for all $N\geq M$ this holds, but they end up being equivalent.

Comment: Have you found any sequence with $\phi_n-n\notin O(1)$ that works? I have a suspicion that this might be an equivalent condition (not just sufficient), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I think that's the case as well, but I haven't found any success towards a proof.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Update: I think I was able to prove that the condition implies $\sum_{n=0}^N(\phi_n-n)=N+O(1)$, which is much stronger than $\sum_{n=0}^N(\phi_n-n)=O(N).$ Edit: Wow! Yep. This implies $\phi_n-n=O(1).$ Thanks for convincing me to continue looking for a proof!

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to write up your proof for others.

Comment: @VarunVejalla So almost immediately after I replied, I realized I assumed the existence of a sequence in my proof that definitely doesn't exist. Thankfully, a week later, I was able to come up with a different proof that definitely works. Much more involved than I initially thought.